# Laravel not rendering html

Tags: php, html, laravel

I tried rendering html markup with content that I have from the database.
It's a bunch of text with a simple `<a>` tag.

this is how it's set in the database field. The database fieldtype is `varchar(200)`

and the collation is `utf8_unicode_ci`

This is the value of the field:

`blablabla &lt;a href=&quot;mailto:info@atmox.nl&quot;&gt;info@atmox.nl&lt;/a&gt; blablabla`

I tried using only the `{!! !!}` blade syntax, but it would just render the markup as plain text. eventually I tried the `html_entity_decode` and `htmlspecialchars_decode` functions, but it's results are the same. plain text.

this is the html part

```
<p>{!! $baan->descriptiond !!}</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to render using `htmlentities($baan->descriptiond)`, `html_entity_decode($string)` on your data and then use {{ $baan->descriptiond }} to render html.

OR

just use a plain laravel blade:

```
{{$baan->descriptiond}}
```

Comment: @rick, did you give this a try ?

Comment: Trying it now, The plain blade didn't work, Now I'm trying the `htmlentities()` and `html_entity_decode()` functions, however, Do I need to apply those to the `$baan->descriptiond` ? Since applying it to the object I parse through won't work..

Comment: yes apply on the `$baan->descriptiond` it should work.

Comment: Like this? `$baan->descriptiond = htmlentities($baan->descriptiond); $baan->descriptiond = html_entity_decode($baan);`
rendering it like: `{{ $baan->descriptiond }}`

Comment: `echo htmlentities($baan->descriptiond);`

Comment: Tried it like: `<p>@php echo html_entity_decode($baan->descriptiond) @endphp</p>` since I can't use echo inside blade brackets. Still plain text..

Comment: ok I have to try it by regenerating the situation at my end. I am revoking my answer here.Will post again.

Comment: New laravel seemed to fix the issue, weird. But thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You really should be able to do this:

```
<p>{!! html_entity_decode($baan->descriptiond) !!}</p>
```

That is assuming `$baan->descriptiond` is something like:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;mailto:info@atmox.nl&quot;&gt;info@atmox.nl&lt;/a&gt;
```

Comment: `$baan->descriptiond` contains some text, example: `You can mail us at &lt;a href=&quot;mailto:info@atmox.nl&quot;&gt;info@atmox.nl&lt;/a&gt; or try the form below.`.

Comment: Tried your solution, but it still shows plain text like: `you can mail us at <a href="mailto:info@entric.nl">info@entric.nl</a> or use the form below:`

Comment: I tested this in Laravel 5.6 and it works. You currently have 3 answers here telling you the same thing.

Comment: Tried all the 3 answers, but to no avail, might it be possible it has something to do with the Database field?

Comment: did you test with the raw data string?

Comment: like: `$string = "blablabla &lt;a href=&quot;mailto:info@atmox.nl&quot;&gt;info@atmox.nl&lt;/a&gt; blablabla";` and then `<p>{!! $string !!}</p>`? Yes I did, still shows plain text...

Comment: I could try making a new Laravel project to test if it works there, Might be something wrong on my end in my laravel setup. Will check back later.

Comment: No, it should be ```{!! html_entity_decode($string) !!}```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do this way

```
{!! $text !!}
```

string will auto escape when you perform {{ }}

For laravel 5

```
{!!html_entity_decode($text)!!}
```

Comment: Doesn't work.. Could something be wrong with my database field?

Comment: @Rick_Jellema Yeah maybe possible, check that too one time

Comment: Database is alright, I could try making a new Laravel project to test if it works there, Might be something wrong on my end in my laravel setup. Will check back later.